# maximum line length for regexp.FindAll*?

Tags: go

Is there a maximum length defined for text lines fed to the `regexp.FindAll*Index()` functions in the regexp package? Running the code below only provides the indices of the last 10 occurrences.

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/QgOw7TzuV4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    line := `VAL_ Status 31 "31-Not Available" 30 "30-Not Defined" 29 "29-Not Defined" 28 "28-Received Temperature Msg" 27 "27 Temp Main (Sub-system)" 26 "26-Throttle Out of Correlation" 25 "25-Received Throttle Pos Msg" 24 "24-Received Throttle Position" 23 "23-Pedal Throttle Position" 22 "22-Throtttle Main (Sub-System)" 21 "21-Oil Makeup Pump Pressure" 20 "20-Engine/B-Average Speeds" 19 "19-A/D Power Regulator" 18 "18-Received Oil Temperature" 17 "17-Oil Temperature Main (IA)" 16 "16-B-Average Speed" 15 "15-Zero Stroke Position" 14 "14-Throttle Main (RVDT)" 13 "13-Engine Speed" 12 "12-Shift Mode Sel-Critical" 11 "11-Shift Mode Sel-Non Critical" 10 "10-Output Driver" 9 "9-Watchdog Off" 8 "8-Steer Gain Solenoid" 7 "7-Vehicle Driveability ID5" 6 "6-Vehicle Driveability ID4" 5 "5-Vehicle Driveability ID3" 4 "4-Vehicle Driveability ID2" 3 "3-Vehicle Driveability ID1" 2 "2-System Power" 1 "1-ROM" 0 "0-No Failures Detected" ;`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(" [0-9] ")

    fmt.Println(re.FindAllStringIndex(line, -1))
}
```

Yields:

`[[677 680] [696 699] [722 725] [753 756] [784 787] [815 818] [846 849] [877 880] [896 899] [906 909]]`

I've tried several of the FindAll*Index funcs and they're all the same.

Comment: The last 10 occurrences are 9-0, which are the only occurrences that match your regex. `" [0-9] "` will match anything that is 'space', 'single digit', 'space'. If you want multiple digits use `" [0-9]+  "`.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin. Bang on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real limit on the number of matches. The reason your regex is not getting more matches is because it needs to be `regexp.MustCompile(" [0-9]+ ")` to match numbers with more than one digit, surrounded by spaces. Right now it only matches `" 0 "` through to `" 9 "`.

Comment: Thanks Blixt - will mark as the answer in a moment. I owe you and @Gavin about 10,000 pints for the whack with the clue-by-four.